# Batch file: How to export to Csv into 1 column A, having commas in file title

Tags: csv, batch-file, cmd, command-line

I have this code that export the file path of a directory/subdirectory into csv list

My problem come when a file have commas in title.
My .csv export, instead having all the file path in one column A, the file path get separated in other columns depending how many commas I have in file title.

I need the file path in one column, first column A

```
@echo off

set "videodir=E:\Export" 
set "exportdir=F:\Dropbox\IMACRO-ACTIV\DataSources
del F:\Dropbox\IMACRO-ACTIV\DataSources\mp4list.csv 2>nul


for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir "%videodir%\*.mp4" /-p /o:gn /B /S 2^>nul') do echo %%I>>"%exportdir%\mp4list.csv"
FOR /F delims^= %%A IN ('DIR "%videodir%" /AD/B/S^|SORT/R') DO RD "%%A"
```

Example title in directory

```
Dua Lipa, Coldplay, Martin Garrix & Kygo, The Chainsmokers Style  (10).mp4
```

in my csv export look like:

```
E:\Export\grup-1\Canal-1\Dua Lipa    Coldplay    Martin Garrix & Kygo    The Chainsmokers Style  (1).mp4
```

and I need to be like bellow

```
E:\Export\grup-1\Canal-1\Dua Lipa, Coldplay, Martin Garrix & Kygo, The Chainsmokers Style  (10).mp4
```

Any Idea how I can improve for this issue?
thank you

Comment: LATER EDIT: solution came to my head after, was `do echo "%%I"` with double ""

Comment: Your question does not make sense to me, not only is there nothing there which would ever replace single, (or multiple adjacent), commas with three space characters, there is also nothing there which would omit comma characters from the output either. Including doublequotes, whilst it may help, (in some situations), with poison characters, should not change anything with regard to commas, as those are not poison characters with `echo`, _(notwithstanding within a `for` variable)_. Perhaps you should take a look at the output from `dir /?` and explain the purpose/use of `/-p`.

Comment: I'm very new to this, I made this script a while ago based on what I found on SO, the presented problem appeared now because I didn't use titles with commas in them in the past. Once I used it, I faced this problem.

All I need is to make a csv list of a directory together with all its subdirectories, with all mp4 files full path and add them in Column A.

There are probably many things that I don't use in this script, but I didn't know what to change or optimize, as long as it worked like that.

Comment: A CSV file usually has field Values Separated by Commas, if your string uses commas, and you don't wish for those to act as separators, you have two options. 1. Change the separators in your CSV to a pipe character, (these are disallowed in filenames, so cannot cause you similar issues). 2. Doublequote the field, (although it may affect translation in some CSV parsers).